# WSO2 CEP Stream Count function restart

Tags: wso2, wso2-cep

I have the following query:

```
from stream1
select count() as item insert into newStream;
```

Is it possible to restart the count() function of a stream?

If not, how can I circumvent this? If possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `count()` or any other aggregate function without a window, there's no way to reset the events that get accumulated within that aggregator. For example if you use a window like below, it will reset the counter after receiving 10 events.

```
from stream1#window.lengthBatch(10)
select count() as item insert into newStream;
```

However, If you need to reset the counter by sending an parameter to it, (i.e `count(bool reset)`) you may have to write your own custom aggregate function as described in the following [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/Writing+a+Custom+Aggregate+Function).

Comment: I am using a window now. making from stream1#window.time(5 min) select count() as item isnert into newStream; but now this gives me only the first 5 minutes. Not a continuos time window.

Comment: Window 'time' is continuous. It's a sliding time window that holds events that arrived during the last windowTime period at a given time, and gets updated for each event arrival and expiry. 

If you want to process events every 5 mins, as a batch, you should use window 'timeBatch". It's a batch (tumbling) time window that holds events that arrive during windowTime periods, and gets updated for each windowTime. 

Refer documentation : https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/Inbuilt+Windows